# How do you calculate how big a 20" circle will appear when it is 500 yards away?

Tags: geometry

How can I calculate how large a 20" circle will appear at various distances (e.g., 500 yards, 400 yards, 300 yards, etc.)? Thanks!

Comment: Can you measure the angle the circle takes in your field of vision at a given distance?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the measurement of "how big does it appear" is given by the angle subtended by
the object at the point of view of the observer.

For a flat disk that is observed by someone along a perpendicular line through the
center of the disk (that is, you are looking at it "straight on"), 
the exact angle subtended is
$$\theta = 2 \arctan \frac {r}{R},$$
where $r$ is the radius of the disk and $R$ is the distance from the observer to
the center of the disk along a line perpendicular to the disk.
For practical purposes, however, the apparent size of a disk can be
approximated by
$$\theta = \frac {2r}{R} = \frac dR$$
where $d$ is the *diameter* of the disk and $R$ is the distance from the observer
to the disk, and where $\theta$ is measured in radians.

A one-inch disk at $100$ yards
subtends an angle of approximately $0.00027778$ radians,
which is approximately $0.0159155$ degrees or $0.95493$ minutes of arc.
In a country that still uses traditional English units for most purposes
(is the US the only such country in the world?),
it is therefore a common practice to use one minute of arc (written $1''$) as
a rough approximation of the angle subtended by a one-inch disk at $100$ yards.

If your disk is $20$ inches in diameter, then, it will subtend roughly
$20$ minutes of arc at $100$ yards, and $\frac 1N$ that much at $N$ times the distance.
For example, at $500$ yards the disk will subtend roughly
$$\left(\frac{20}{5}\right)'' = 4''.$$

Answer (score 0):

It depends what "how large" means. If you mean the angle that it subtends, 
$$
{\rm angle}={{\rm width}\over{\rm distance}}.
$$
If the object is very large or close by, you need to use a trigonometric formula
$$
{\rm angle}=2\arctan\left({\rm width}\over2\times{\rm distance}\right).
$$
If the width is much smaller than the distance the upper formula is enough. This gives the angle in radians; for the angle in degrees, multiply by $180/\pi$.